# Critical CSS with SASS

Tags: html, css, sass

We're optimizing our website so that we find out the minimal set of CSS needed to display the top of the page, minify it and add it inline to the HTML document. We tried to use tools such as criticalCSS and Penthouse for this, but they include too many selectors so we'd like to specify the styles to include by hand.

What we'd like to do is something like this:

```
.body-normal
  +critical()
  background-color: #fafafa
  color: #606060

.footer
  background-color: #c0c0c0
  color: #656565
```

Preferred CSS output from the above:

```
.body-normal {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  color: #606060;
}
```

Is there some way to accomplish something like this? I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/benedfit/46da533805566141c42f) that would otherwise do what we want but since we have a lot of rules already we'd like to avoid wrapping everything in `@include critical(false)` if possible.

Comment: What you're asking for is not even remotely possible in a million years because that's not how `@content` mixins work.

Comment: @cimmanon: Please read the question again. Note the repeated phrase "something like this". It doesn't have to be mixins, and SASS doesn't have to be the only tool in the chain.

Comment: Tool requests are off-topic here, you should know that by now.

Comment: @cimmanon: I'm not asking for tool suggestions. I'm asking for a way to solve a well-defined problem in SASS. If a possible solution involves using an external tool such as PostCSS I don't think it turns my question into a tool request.

Comment: If you would like to know how to do this using PostCSS, I suggest you ask another question.

Comment: Our build process uses SASS and not PostCSS (yet) so I'd really prefer a SASS solution.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to prevent Sass from generating the output for a selector is by wrapping it an if/else statement.  Whether that's in the form of manually writing out the if/else each time or by using an `@content` mixin that has an if/else inside of it, the result is the same.

```
@if $critical
    .body-normal
        background-color: #fafafa
        color: #606060
```